# dump html code on browser without using html file

Tags: c#, .net

Earlier, I used `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` to pass website url and open it in internet explorer.

Now, I have a HTML page code in database. I am working on a Windows application. I need to dump code on browser when click on windows application button. What is best .Net library to perform this task?

I looked at `Process.Start()` function, but it take html file name. In my situation, I dont have html file.

Comment: Do you have an option to create a web page (simple ASP.NET page) or web service to retrieve the contents out of the db and just Response.Write the result? That way you can have a static URL and just manipulate the html page code in your db at will. Though it's hard to understand what you're scenario really is without more details of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @nithins: I think he's working on a desktop application...

Comment: Yes, I am working on desktop application using wpf.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at embedding the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control into your application.

You can call the `NavigateToString` method and pass the HTML source from your database as a string for it to render.

Since you're using WPF, there's a nice [guide](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article840-working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf-.aspx) on how to integrate a WebBrowser control into your application.

Comment: No, application dont need an embedded explorer.

Comment: @Syed: Well then, you'll have to write the HTML to a file and then start the external browser with that file as an argument